# Upload files to the plugin menu

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I'm currently trying to build a wordpress plugin. I'd like its users to be able to add an upload file to the settings field menu of my plugin and then to be registered into the wordpress database, is there some way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've been down that road. Take a look at `wp_handle_upload`, which will upload your file to the /uploads directory and then `wp_insert_attachment` and `wp_generate_attachment_metadata` to list said upload in the media library as an attachment which will 'register it in the wordpress database'. Then you can query attachments like this:

```
$attachments = get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'attachment') );
```

Answer (score 0):

The media manager is loaded using jQuery.
Here is a sample JS file that I've found. I hope it helps.

```
(function($) {

$(document).ready( function() {
    var file_frame; // variable for the wp.media file_frame

    // attach a click event (or whatever you want) to some element on your page
    $( '#frontend-button' ).on( 'click', function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // if the file_frame has already been created, just reuse it
        if ( file_frame ) {
            file_frame.open();
            return;
        } 

        file_frame = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
            title: $( this ).data( 'uploader_title' ),
            button: {
                text: $( this ).data( 'uploader_button_text' ),
            },
            multiple: false // set this to true for multiple file selection
        });

        file_frame.on( 'select', function() {
            attachment = file_frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();

            // do something with the file here
            $( '#frontend-button' ).hide();
            $( '#frontend-image' ).attr('src', attachment.url);
        });

        file_frame.open();
    });
});

})(jQuery);
```